# PowerShell package source confirmation

Tags: powershell, nuget, powershell-cmdlet, trusted, oneget

I'm trying to create a function that will automatically install, update and import **on demand** a PowerShell module from repository PSGallery and this will be run on a build server so I have to avoid any kind of confirmation prompts. This function will be called quite often and will not try to install or update modules if the module is already loaded to the session (only the first time).

```
# Already imported? Let's not go further with updates and import again...
if (Get-Module -Name $moduleName)
{
    Write-Host "'$moduleName' is already imported to the current session!"

    return
}
```

If the module is not already installed, I will try to install it. The problem is when I get to the step that I have to install the NuGet PackageManagement provider (before importing PowerShellGet module needed to install modules from PSGallery). I do the following cmdlet:

```
Install-PackageProvider -Name "NuGet" -Confirm:$false -Verbose
```

But I get the following confirmation prompt:

[image]

I could solve this issue by using the `-Force` parameter like that:

```
Install-PackageProvider -Name "NuGet" -Confirm:$false -Force -Verbose
```

But the problem I see with that solution (might not be a big deal) is that using `-Force` will download and install again NuGet every time even if the installed version is up to date. Without the `-Force` parameter, it will just skip it if the version is up to date and I would much rather that.

Is there a way to set the package source 'https://oneget.org/nuget-2.8.5.208.package.swidtag' as trusted so I don't get the confirmation prompt again without having to use `-Force` parameter?

Comment: Powershell 3 and up has an `Unblock-File` cmdlet. Maybe that could help? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/unblock-file?view=powershell-6

Answer (score 1):

Actually, if you run `Get-PackageProvider -Name "NuGet" -Force` it will automatically download and install it if its not installed. If it is installed, it returns NuGet as an object. My PowerShell version is 5.1.14393.1480.

---

**Original Response**:

Maybe you could just check to see if its available and then run your command?

```
$NuGetProvider = Get-PackageProvider -Name "NuGet" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if ( -not $NugetProvider )
{
    Install-PackageProvider -Name "NuGet" -Confirm:$false -Force -Verbose
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I really like it and thought about it but how can I manage updates with that solution? I would have to find a way to check if the installed package provider NuGet version is up to date (in the Elseif statement maybe).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help, but here goes nothing:

Can you use the cmd version of try-catch using errorlevel?

```
Install-PackageProvider -Name "NuGet" -Confirm:$false -Verbose
if errorlevel 1 GOTO Forced
exit /b
:Forced
Install-PackageProvider -Name "NuGet" -Confirm:$false -Force -Verbose
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using the -ForceBoostrap parameter on Get-PackageProvider, e.g.

```
Get-PackageProvider -Name "nuget" -ForceBootstrap
```